# Eventualmente ocorre java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, eclipse, exceção, debug

Fiz um algoritmo simples de um livro e nele existem dois possíveis resultados. Para testar esses resultados tenho de executar o programa várias vezes até que a Math.random() gere os números possíveis e exiba os dois possíveis resultados. O estranho foi que quando fui executando o código chegou um ponto em que ele apresentou uma mensagem

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
>       at matrizReferencia3.Hobbits.main(Hobbits.java:25)"

Mas se eu executo o programa novamente ele volta a apresentar um resultado. Gostaria de entender o motivo dessa mensagem aparecer, se é algo perigoso que estou fazendo no meu código.

```
package matrizReferencia3;

public class Hobbits {
String name;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Hobbits[] h = new Hobbits[3];
    int z = 0;
    int posicao = 5;

    while(z < 3){ 
        h[z] = new Hobbits();
        z++;
    }

    while (posicao > 3){
    posicao =(int) (Math.random() *10);
    }

    if (posicao == 2){
        h[posicao].name = "sam";
    }
    else{
        h[posicao].name = "frodo";
    }
    System.out.print(h[posicao].name + " is a ");
    System.out.println("good Hobbit name");
}
}
```

Comment: Seu `while (posicao > 3)`deveria ser `while (posicao >= 3)`, pois 3 está fora do index (0 a 2). Se ele gerar 3, cai fora do `while` e entra no `else` com 3 como _index_.

Comment: Por que você não faz `posicao =(int) (Math.random() *2);` para obter números até dois, aí evitaria o `while` ?

Comment: Realmente, falta de atenção minha, muito obrigado cara!

Comment: Este exemplo não pode ser reproduzido? Aparentemente o Earendul e o ramaral conseguiram, eu voto por reabrir.

Comment: "ou é um erro de digitação"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro indica que você está a tentar aceder a um item do array `h` cujo índice é superior ao tamanho desse array.

O array foi definido como tendo 3 itens:

```
Hobbits[] h = new Hobbits[3];
```

Os itens terão como índice os valores 0 para o primeiro, 1 para o segundo e 2 para o terceiro.
Na parte do código, onde é gerado um índice aleatório, é permitido que o valor 3 seja gerado:

```
while (posicao > 3){
    posicao =(int) (Math.random() *10);
}
```

Para que isso não aconteça faça com que o valor não seja maior que 2:

```
while (posicao > 2){
    posicao =(int) (Math.random() *10);
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, muita falta de atenção da minha parte. Não vai acontecer novamente. Abraços!